# gitlab-runner & fastlane - Can't find OneSignal Extension Provisioning File

Tags: gitlab, fastlane

I am trying to use Gitlab CI/CD feature to build and distribute my iOS app. To do that, I made an iMac as a Gitlab-Runner to build and deploy.

But, I have met an issue that can't build my iOS app. Because OneSignal iOS app extension can't find a provisioning profile to build it.

```
❌  [BCEROR]Code Signing Error: "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
```

Here is my code to build it.

```
automatic_code_signing
increment_build_number
increment_version_number

gym(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", 
  scheme: "MyApp", 
  clean: true, 
  silent: false,
  export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates", 
  include_bitcode: false,
  export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
         provisioningProfiles: { 
            "com.test.myapp" => "My APP",
            "com.test.myapp.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" => "MY APP Provisioning Profile"
          }
      })
```

If someone could help me, I really appreciate it.